# How can I build multiple modules in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have maven multi-module project in IntelliJ. Each of the modules is stored in a separate git repository.
I need to create some shortcut commands, How can i build all modules at once ?

Comment: You need to have all modules under the same IDE project, then use Build | Build Project action.

Answer (score 1):

See [create maven multi module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_multi_module) from Jetbrains